# How do I update a subscriber's email address in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Simple question - I have a subscriber in a data extension. We'll call it Customer_Sign_Up. I just received a phone call from him asking if we can update his email address.

How do I do this? I just want to go in, find his 'record' and write his new email adcdress in. I can't find a way to do this as going into the data extension only shows the first 200 records and I can't search by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you export it, remove the row and re-import.  However, now you can edit Data Extension rows using [Contact Builder](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/data_extensions/).  Here's the navigation path:

[Cloud Icon] -> Audience Builder -> Contact Builder -> Email Data -> Data Extensions > (find your DE) -> Records -> (search for row, check the box) -> Edit Record -> (make your changes) -> Save

[image: Contact Builder DE row edit]

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much this is exactly what I need. ExactTarget/Marketing Cloud's online help is totally useless - I googed a dozen varieties on this question and almost nothing comes up. Thanks again!

Comment: Agreed.  BEHOLD THE POWER OF SFSE IN THE SFMC ECO-SYSTEM!

Comment: This will update the email address in the data extension, but not in the AllSubscribers. As far as I understand, this means that all emails sent manually will still go to the original email address - the one on the AllSubscribers table?

Answer (score 0):

To update an email address from All Subscribers, you can go to the All Subscribers page and do a search for the email you want to change. With the General Tab selected in the Properties window, type the new email address in the field and click ok to save.

You would then use Contact Builder to apply the same changes to any Data Extension the email address is associated with.